# Vertical Flexslider partial slide display issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

The Vertical flexslider displaying the partial slides.The slides are getting cut from top bottom.Its the issue with different image sizes.

Here is the code:

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({ 
        animation: "slide", 
        animationLoop: false, 
        controlNav: false, 
        direction: "vertical", 
        pausePlay: true, 
        start: function(slider) { 
            $('body').removeClass('loading'); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

Here is the jsfidle url   jsfiddle.net/va4R6

Comment: Your Effort ? Code ? jsfiddle/plunkr ?

Comment: $(window).load(function(){
   $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: false,
  controlNav: false,
  direction: "vertical",
  pausePlay: true,
     start: function(slider){
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
      }
      });
   });

Comment: You may need a better question with examples of one that works and one that doesn't so that people can help.

Comment: Vertical flex slider is giving issue with height of slides the slides are partially displaying.Here is the url please check  http://jsfiddle.net/va4R6/

Comment: Hi Vaibhav I have attached the jsfiddle url.will you please check?? Thanks

Comment: You might post some pictures with annotations that will show the problem. That will help people to understand what is exactly your problem.

Comment: @user3690897 Please add both your code and the jsfiddle link to the original question as an edit. This will allow people to easily view important information associated with your question.

Answer (score 1):

dont put the margin or padding for the 'li' element (slide of the flexslider), instead of that put a wrapper for the content inside the 'li' , put all content into it and add required margin or padding to the wrapper. this can avoid the partial display in vertical flexslider